# Problem with the instalation of react-curved-text

Tags: reactjs, text, module, node-modules

I try to curve a text with react-curved-text and even if it is compiled succesfully I see this warning "TypeError: Object(...) is not a function"

Here is my GitHub
Could somebody take a look please?

https://github.com/AnnaVarda/react-full-site

I tried to create a global.d.ts with module inside and again is not working

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to your React version. Currently, [react-curved-text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-curved-text) requires **React 18.0.0 or later**.

You need to update **react** and **react-dom** versions in your app.

In your **package.json**, replace these lines:

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
...
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
```

with these lines:

```
"react": "^18.0.0",
...
"react-dom": "^18.0.0",
```

then run `npm install` command, and then the error will be gone.